# How to phrase this identity in differential form language?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

If the vector field $\mathbf B$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is constant, then the vector field
$$
\mathbf A = \frac 1 2 \mathbf B \times \mathbf r
$$
satisfies
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B.
$$

This can be proven by writing out in components.
I would like to phrase this identity and prove it in differential form language (I am not sure if this is possible, but it's worth a try). I have tried the following:

- $\mathbf A$ becomes a 1-form $A$
- $\mathbf B$ becomes a 2-form $\mathcal B$
- $\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B $ becomes $\mathcal B = dA $

How to continue? I realize I will need to put hodge duals in appropriate places to realize the cross product.

Comment: First things first. (1) What do you mean by saying $\mathbf B$ is independent of $\mathbf r$? (2) If you want $\mathbf B$ to be the curl of someone, then it is necessary that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf B = 0$. So are you trying to do the Poincaré lemma here that any closed $2$-form on all of $\Bbb R^3$ is (explicitly) exact?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin (1) From wikipedia: "In vector calculus, a vector field is an assignment of a vector to each point in a subset of space". By $\mathbf B$ being independent of $\mathbf r$, I mean that the same vector is assigned to each point of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This works because each point of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the same. (2) That is not the same as what I am trying to show.

Comment: Well, if you mean $\mathbf B$ is a *constant* vector field, then of course my questions are answered affirmatively.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I edited the question to use the word constant, but I am not sure if your second question is answered affirmatively, and your first question is an open question.

Comment: OK, of course it's an easy computation to see that $
\mathcal B = d\left(\frac12\big(b_1(ydz-zdy))+b_2(zdx-xdz)+b_3(xdy-ydx)\big)\right)$, but I don't see an obvious way to make you happy, as there is no good formula for $\star(\beta\wedge\eta)$, where $\beta$ and $\eta$ are $1$-forms. I'm betting this is a place where @Muphrid's favorite geometric algebra may be more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

@Ted Shifrin mentioned in the comments that this translation is possible using Geometric Algebra.  That's true, but also shows how to further transform this relation to one with differential forms.

With

$$I = \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3,$$

and the identity $ \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y} = I (\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y}) $, the pair of identities becomes

$$I \mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{{2}} \mathbf{B} \wedge \mathbf{r}$$
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{A} = I \mathbf{B}.$$

Introducing a bivector dual $ \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} = -I \mathbf{B} $, these can be written

$$\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{{2}} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} \cdot \mathbf{r}$$
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{A} = -\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}, \qquad (1)$$

As with the coordinate expansion of the original 3D vector result, this can be verified by direct expansion.  Assuming an antisymmetric scalar $ B_{ab} = -B_{ba} $, the bivector coordinate expansion is

$$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} = \frac{1}{{2}} B_{ab} \mathbf{e}_a \wedge \mathbf{e}_b.$$

Expanding out (1) gives

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{A}&=\mathbf{e}_i \partial_i \wedge \left( \frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab} (\mathbf{e}_a \wedge \mathbf{e}_b) \cdot (\mathbf{e}_s x_s)\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab}\mathbf{e}_i \wedge \left(  (\mathbf{e}_a \wedge \mathbf{e}_b) \cdot (\mathbf{e}_s \delta_{i s})\right)  \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}}B_{ab}\mathbf{e}_i \wedge \left(  (\mathbf{e}_a \wedge \mathbf{e}_b) \cdot \mathbf{e}_i\right)  \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}}B_{ab}\mathbf{e}_i \wedge \left(  \mathbf{e}_a \delta_{b i} - \mathbf{e}_b \delta_{a i}\right)  \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}}B_{ab}\left( \mathbf{e}_b \wedge \mathbf{e}_a - \mathbf{e}_a \wedge \mathbf{e}_b\right)  \\ &=-\frac{1}{{2}} B_{ab} \mathbf{e}_a \wedge \mathbf{e}_b \\ &= -\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}\end{aligned}$$

Mapping the Geometric Algebra form to differential forms should (I believe) just require using differentials as the basis, and using the $ d $ operator in place of the bivector curl $ \boldsymbol{\nabla} \wedge $.  With

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} &= \frac{1}{{2}} B_{ab} dx_a \wedge dx_b \\ \mathbf{r} &= x_a dx_a,\end{aligned}$$

that is

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{A} &= \frac{1}{{2}} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} \cdot \mathbf{r} \\
d \mathbf{A} &= -\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}.\qquad (2)
\end{aligned}$$

A verification by coordinate expansion appears to give the right results.  First, explicitly expanding the 1-form $\mathbf{A}$:

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{A} &= \frac{1}{{2}} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}} \cdot \mathbf{r} \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab} (dx_a \wedge dx_b) \cdot (dx_s x_s) \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab} x_s ( dx_a \delta_{bs} - dx_b \delta_{as} ) \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab} (x_b dx_a - x_a dx_b).\end{aligned}$$

Application of the differential operator gives

$$\begin{aligned}d\mathbf{A} &= \frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab} d(x_b dx_a - x_a dx_b) \\ &=\frac{1}{{4}} B_{ab} (dx_b \wedge dx_a - dx_a \wedge dx_b) \\ &=-\frac{1}{{2}} B_{ab} dx_a \wedge dx_b \\ &=-\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}.\end{aligned}$$

While the 2-form $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}$ can be related to a 1-form using the hodge-star operator, that doesn't really appear required for the identity (2) to be valid.